# Changing XML file to Application File

Tags: xml

I copies some games from home.  They are .EXE files.  However, when I try to copy them onto another computer, when my cursor hovers over them, it says they are XML files ... even though they are named .EXE.  If I continue with the copy process, I cannot open them because they copy as .EXE.XML.  How can I change the properties to show them as applications, and not as XML files?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to rename them, you have to display the file extensions, from the folder options (more details about that [here, for example](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_display_filename_suffixes_windows_vista.html)):

[image: folder options]

Then you should see the .exe.xml full extension, and you should simply rename the file (press F2 on a selected file, or choose "Rename" in the right mouse button menu), to get rid of the xml extension.